Can someone give me an example of what a probability distribution looks like and its notation?
What is a probability distribution of a random variable X and what is the typical notation for a probability distribution?
Can someone show me an example of what a probability distribution looks like and its notation?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions has a ton of examples of distributions (something around 200? I think), most with links to pages about them and most of those have pictures (of cdf and density / pmf), along with some notation, though notation can vary. More general details on distributions is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution . There are many ways to specify a distribution.
